# Delay batch files in between commands

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe, delay

How do I delay batch files in between commands, with say a once second delay, or even less? I've tried using the ping null command, but it never seems too work for me?

```
 ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 > null
```

But it never seems too work. Is there another - yet easier way too do this? Thanks.

Comment: `>null` That should be `>nul`.

Comment: A good summary of the various techniques to halt a batch file process: https://www.robvanderwoude.com/wait.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How do I delay batch files between commands, with a 1s delay, or even less?

You can't delay for < 1s using built-in commands.

As an alternative to `ping` you can use `timeout`:

```
timeout 1 /nobreak
```

- Delay for 1 second and ignore user keystrokes.

This works in Window 7 or later.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [timeout](http://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html) - Delay execution for a few seconds or minutes, for use within a batch file.

Answer (score 2):

For a one second delay you need `-n 2` since the 1 second wait is inserted between *consecutive* pings. In general you need `N+1` (successful) pings for an `N` seconds delay.